# Use SMO to locate correct backup path

Tags: c#, restore, openfiledialog, smo

I am developing a software using a MSSQL database for holding the data. In the program I implemented a function for creating a backup with SMO.

Now I am trying to implement a restore function. It works without any problems when the user has to insert the path manually. But I want to implement a select file dialog like this one the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is opening when selecting a custom medium (see on the screenshot).
[image: SSMS Select dialog]

I already found the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` class with the method `EnumDirectories`, but it returns only directory names and no files. When I confirm the selection I need the path in format **C:\Directory\FileName.bak**.

Is it possible to meet my needs with using SMO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many months ago I found a solution. I just developed a custom SelectFileDialog which is able to connecto to SQL server and work with the following SQL functions:

For searching available drives:

```
exec xp_fixeddrives
```

For reading folders and files:

```
exec xp_dirtree 'PATH', 1, 1
```

The **PATH** variable is dynamicly replaced depends on which folder is expanded by the user. It works without problems.